# Exception appeared after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store app that was running fine for the last 6 months with no exceptions and a 50 minutes average app usage for day (dashboard statistics). Bad ratings will ruin my 4.5 average rating and **I need to solve this fast so I will give a bounty to whom helps me solve it.** (I have to wait 2 days to be eligible but I will do it)

Today I installed Windows 8.1 update and now my app crashes everytime. This is what is happening:

I have a `MediaElement` control in my main page and the user can change its source. It has an `MediaFailed` event callback attached.

**Problem 1**

Till now `MediaElement` played fine every source user would choose but now it always fails and `MediaFailed` event is triggered.

`MediaElement` `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs.ErrorMessage` is "MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_DECODE : HRESULT - 0xC00D36B4"

**Problem 2**

This is `MediaFailed` callback that is causing the exception:

```
private async void MediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog notAvailableDialog = new MessageDialog("Not available", "Ooops");
    notAvailableDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ok"));
    await notAvailableDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

If I catch the exception app shows the dialog and it does not crash. This is the exception:

**Message:** [System.InvalidOperationException] = {"A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)"}

**Stacktrace:** at Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog.ShowAsync() at MainPage.d__30.MoveNext() in MainPage.xaml.cs:line 296

### UPDATE 1

Problem 2 solved. `MediaFailed` event is fired twice and because of that 2 `MessageDialog` were showed at the same time causing the exception. I solved it by not showing more `MessageDialog` till there is none open.

Problem 1 is not solved. It is making my app useless. My `MediaElement` is throwing the following error: `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_DECODE`. It means: `An error occurred while decoding the media resource.`

**Another strange behavior is:** when deploying app to Simulator it works fine but when deploying to Local Machine decoding fails.

**What may be causing that?** Before installing Windows 8.1 update decode was working fine.

### UPDATE 2

Problem 1 was solved after restarting the computer. Some wasted hours because a CODEC conflict after installing the update.

Comment: Show more of the stack trace... The callback isn't causing the exception - it is trigger BY the exception. Show us the code that runs right before this callback is called. By the way, `A method was called at an unexpected time.' almost always results from trying to get the results of an asynchronous method before it was completed, so ensure you `await` all async methods.

Comment: might be a problem with the async void. Try wrapping the ShowAsync method in a try catch

Comment: @DavidH I am sure it is the callback. The code right before is just: `myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(myuri);`. If you want more details ask please. Did you mean the exception of MediaElement when it tries to load a source?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot the exception in my question was caught wrapping ShowAsync method in a try catch. Maybe I was not clear :/